# How to embed interactive content on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm interested in sharing embedded content on social media.  My goal is to allow real estate agents to share a slide show of a house they're selling, and to this end I'd really like to be able to embed content rather than linking back to it.

A great example of what I want to do is [here, on the authorStream facebook page.](https://www.facebook.com/authorstream/posts/10153256361684250)

How are they embedding this content? Do they have some deal with facebook?

Comment: That is simply a Flash file embedded as “video” via the Open Graph meta tags in the URL they shared in that post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in how they did this, I recommend you use the [OpenGraph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1JThFSp) and observe the tags they added to their page to make this content visible in this form. Here's a sample:

```
<meta name="og_site_name" property="og:site_name" content="authorSTREAM" />
<meta property="og:title" content="15 Steps to Prepare for an Interview -Sachin Karpe " />
<meta property="og:description" content="Sachin Karpe shares few steps before you walk for an interview.- authorSTREAM Presentation" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="632248145" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="26672622939" />


<meta property="og:image" content="http://authorstream.s3.amazonaws.com/content/2177074_635379786451345000.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.authorstream.com/Presentation/sachinkarpe-2177074-15-steps-prepare-interview-sachin-karpe/" /> 
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.authorstream.com/Player.swf?p=2177074_635379786451345000&r=1&pt=3&fb=1&mb=1&nb=1&pl=as&ap=0&c=#dfdfdf&fi=1" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.authorstream.com/player.swf?p=2177074_635379786451345000&r=1&pt=3&fb=1&mb=1&nb=1&pl=as&ap=0&c=#dfdfdf&fi=1" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="402" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="481" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Last, you could check the [Open Graph Get Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started) documentation from Facebook

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the OpenGraph Debugger link too, helpful to learn how to fish

Comment: Does this require permission or whitelisting from facebook? we tried this without success.

Comment: Nowadays I can't be sure. If you've implemented the same steps as the sample page provided in the question and still are unsuccessful with this, I would recommend filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, with the exact reproduction steps you took, the sample page where this is actually working and they can determine with more certainty if whitelisting is necessary, or this is an implementation issue, or maybe this functionality was disabled? As you can see, it can be multiple causes.